# Computmg the powers of a complex number?

Tags: core-language, homework, number-representation

this is the complex number im dealing with

```
    zb=(1/7)* (Cos[Pi/3]+I Sin[Pi/3])
```

I need to represent for the first 10 powers in the plane. I also need to label the points with "z to the power n(n is the power for which i elevate zb)

I need to label the axes, I need to do all this in mathematica

My questions

1. How can I represent a complex number in mathematica
2. How can I represent for the first 10 powers the plane.
3. How can I label each point on the graph to the corresponding power?

my professor gave me a hint to use the callout[] command in mathematica. thank you!

Comment: thanks! i got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Show[
    (1/7)*(Cos[Pi/3] + I Sin[Pi/3])^Range[6] // ReIm // 
        ListPlot[ # -> Range@6] &,
    (1/7)*(Cos[Pi/3] + I Sin[Pi/3])^Range[7, 10] // ReIm // 
        ListPlot[# -> Range[7, 10], LabelingFunction -> Above] &
    ]
```

[image]

Comment: how can I label the points with the phrase "z to the power n(n corresponding from 1 to 10)

Comment: Table[Callout[z1^n, Row[{"z to the power ", n}]], how could i make this work? thank you

Comment: @Aran `(1/7)*(Cos[Pi/3] + I Sin[Pi/3])^Range[6] // ReIm // 
    ListPlot[MapThread[Callout, {#, Range@6}]] &` the effect is the same.